# How to stack 2 divs left and align last div right using Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to stack 2 divs on top of each other aligned left and make the last div align right.
They should all 3 be vertically centered.

This is the markup I have. This can't be changed.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">First</div>
    <div class="second">Second</div>
    <div class="third">Third</div>
</div>
```

This is how i want it to be.

[image]

Is this possible using Flex and not changing the markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```css
    .box{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:5px;
}
.box:nth-of-type(3){
  align-self:end;
}
.con{
  display:flex;
  width:350px;
  height:250px;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="box">001</div>
  <div class="box">002</div>
  <div class="box">003</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem, without modifying the markup. I was missing a height on the container.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add wrapper divs to those three divs you could do it as following:

You can wrap your first two divs in another div and apply `justify-content: space-between` to the container.
To center them vertically, add `display: flex;` and `flex-direction: column` to the wrapper class and add `justify-content: center`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">First</div>
    <div class="box">Second</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="box">Third</div>
  </div>
</div>
```